# string vs String in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, naming-conventions

For type declarations as [here](https://github.com/cyga/real-world-haskell/blob/master/ch16/HttpRequestParser.hs#L21), `String` is used:

```
p_pair :: CharParser () (String, Maybe String)
```

And in some other places as [here](https://github.com/cyga/real-world-haskell/blob/master/ch16/HttpRequestParser.hs#L31), `string` is used:

```
req = ctor <$ string name <* char ' '
```

Note the capitalization difference between `String` and `string`

What is the difference between `String` and `string` in Haskell?

Comment: `String` is a type, `string` is a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Haskell *value and type variable names* start with a lower-case letter while *value and type constructor names, type synonyms, and classes* start with a capital letter. For example:

```
data Tree a = Empty
            | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

height Empty = 0
height (Node _ l r) = max (height l) (height r) + 1
```

Note that `Tree` is a type constructor name, `Empty` and `Node` are value constructor names and `height` is a function name. In your case `String` is the name of the type "string" which is simply a synonym for `[Char]`, while `string` is a function.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use the name `Void` as you have. That's a common name for the canonical uninhabited type. See, for example, `Data.Void`.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like `string` is the function from `Text.Parsec.Char` while `String` is the usual Type.

In fact, in the same chapter of [RealWorldHaskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html), this function is explicitly mentioned under 'Choices and Errors;:

> This must be done carefully. Recall that our earlier definition of eol was simply char '\n'. There is a parser called string that we can use to match the multi-character patterns. Let's start by thinking of how we would add support for \n\r

Answer (score 3):

One is [a type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html), the other is [a function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Char.html).